# Will the per-app vm memory budget change if I upgrade OS from 2.1 to 2.3.3?

Tags: android

My Droid phone has OS 2.1 and the per-app VM budget is 24M bytes. If I upgrade its OS to 2.3.3, will the per-app VM memory budget of my Droid phone increase to 32M bytes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically dependent on a number of variables. You can also manually change this value in your Build.prop file if you are a rooted user.